# Can't install C-based modules like lxml and Cython on Python 3.6 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, debian, cython, raspbian

I built Python 3.6 from source and am trying to install lxml. Trying to install it from pip gives the following error:

```
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/libxml2 -Isrc -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c src/lxml/etree.c -o build/temp.linux-armv6l-3.6/src/lxml/etree.o -w
    src/lxml/etree.c:91:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    Compile failed: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    cc -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c /tmp/xmlXPathInitln68cjsn.c -o tmp/xmlXPathInitln68cjsn.o
    cc tmp/xmlXPathInitln68cjsn.o -L/usr/lib -lxml2 -o a.out
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

The same error is raised if I try to install Cython to compile lxml from source. I installed libxml2-dev and libxslt1-dev, but python3.6-dev, which is apparently also required, is not found in Raspbian repository. I added the following line to /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian sid main
```

But when trying to install it afterwards, I receive the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libdbus-1-3 : Breaks: dbus (< 1.9.16-1~) but 1.6.8-1+deb7u1 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

In fact, this error is raised on any package that is found in Debian repository that is not in Raspbian one. What can I do about this?

Comment: The first error in the output above is "fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory". Did you install the package "python3-dev" or "python3.6-dev"? This should provide the missing header file.

Comment: python3-dev installs wrong version (3.2) and I described my attempts with python3.6-dev later in the post.

Comment: I mixed the different infos, sorry. As danny mentions, the install from source should have installed the Python.h file. Don't mix with "apt-get install" packages and don't mix debian repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you installed Python from source, you should have the header files already. Should also use header files for the version that you built as opposed to the version in the package manager.

Either

- Add the source code directory to includes used by GCC (`gcc -I<dir>`) or
- Install the from source package in a system directory that is automatically included like `/usr/include` or `/usr/local/include`

The second option is probably easiest and should be possible from the standard configure/make scripts.

Comment: Hm, can't get either option to work.
1. This seems to be correct way to pass arguments to gcc when installing via pip: `pip3.6 install lxml  --global-option="-I/usr/local/include/"` . However, this gives me an error `error: option -I not recognized`
2. What do you mean by installing the source package? Or did you mean reinstalling Python from scratch? I tried copying the Include folder to /usr/local/include and renaming it to 'python3.6' (since I already had a 'python3.5' folder with similar contents there), but it didn't work.

Comment: By installing the package I mean `make install`. From the output above, `/usr/local/include/python3.6m` is already in includes path. That directory should contain a `Python.h` file, otherwise `make install` or manually copy them there.

Comment: Oh, I see the problem. I renamed it to 'python3.6' instead of 'python3.6m'. I managed to finally install lxml after fixing this (and slapping on additional 1 Gb of swap to prevent out-of-memory crash, and waiting for 3 hours). Thanks!